Substitute to pvlib.forecast?
I'm tasked to use pvlib to create GHI forecasts for a specific location using GFS model data. I know that pvlib. Forecast has been deprecated, so I'm wondering if pvlib has any substitute for that.
I've also tried Solcast, but I don't think I can input GFS into it.

I recommend using Herbie [1] for retrieving recent or historical GFS forecasts (or other numerical weather prediction model outputs in addition to GFS, for that matter, like HRRR, GEFS, ECMWF open products, etc.). Herbie is a Python package you can use to:

Download numerical weather prediction datasets (HRRR, RAP, GFS, IFS, etc.) from NOMADS, NODD partners (Amazon, Google, Microsoft), ECMWF open data, and the University of Utah Pando Archive System.

I think that this pvlib fork [2] was created to keep pvlib.forecast working (based on a comment in the pvlib google group that I can't link to because I've run out of links...) but I have not tested it, and can't really comment further.
A rough (and incomplete) example for getting GHI from GFS with Herbie is in the pvlib google group here [3]. And the first two notebooks in this repo have some examples of using Herbie for HRRR-based forecasts [4]. Another example of using Herbie for HRRR data is pasted below (originally shared here [5]), and results in this output:
sample plot of forecasted GHI, temperature, and wind speed from HRRR
There's also Open-Meteo.com's website and API, e.g., [6]. Note that it requires a license for commercial use.
[1] https://github.com/blaylockbk/Herbie
[2] https://github.com/kahemker/pvlib-python/tree/thredds-v5-support-pvlib0.9
[3] https://groups.google.com/g/pvlib-python/c/MRZMGjdMjms/m/slLf-zDuAwAJ
[4] https://github.com/williamhobbs/solar-fleet-forecast-probability-tool
[5] https://github.com/blaylockbk/Herbie/issues/182#issuecomment-1792598996
[6] https://open-meteo.com/en/docs#latitude=51.2&longitude=10.4&hourly=temperature_2m,windspeed_10m,shortwave_radiation&models=gfs_global
# this takes about 5-10 minutes to run
from herbie import FastHerbie
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

# range of initialization times. I think it needs at least 2 times for 
# merge steps later to work properly
DATES = pd.date_range(start='2023-06-20 06:00',
                      end='2023-06-21 06:00',
                      freq='24H')

# range of forecast lead times. I think it needs at least 2 times for 
# merge steps later to work properly
fxx = range(28,46)

# list of forecasted variables. GHI, 2m temperature, and U/V 10 m wind
# changing the number of variables results in a linear change in run time
variables_list = ['DSWRF:surface','TMP:2 m','UGRD:10 m','VGRD:10 m']
FH = FastHerbie(DATES, model="HRRR", product="sfc", fxx=fxx)

# loop through variables, write output datasets to a dictionary
ds_dict = {}
for i in range(0,len(variables_list)):
    ds_dict[i] = FH.xarray(variables_list[i], remove_grib=True)

# merge datasets, calculate wind speed and temp in Celsius
ds = xr.merge(ds_dict.values(), compat='override')
ds = ds.assign(t2m_c=ds['t2m'] - 273.15)
ds = ds.assign(wspd=(ds['u10']**2 + ds['v10']**2)**0.5)

# pull out data for a location of interest into a dataframe
lat, lon = 33.52, -86.81
df = ds.herbie.nearest_points(points=(lon,lat)).to_dataframe()

# make a plot
# I'm using stepped lines, which is usually appropriate for hourly data, 
# but HRRR returns instantaneous values, so...? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# primary y-axis
ax1.plot(df.valid_time,df.dswrf, drawstyle='steps-mid', label='dswrf')
ax1.set_ylabel('DSWRF (W/m^2)')

# secondary y-axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot([]) # empty plot element, so that the next line is a different color.
ax2.plot(df.valid_time,df.t2m_c, drawstyle='steps-mid', label='t2m_c')
ax2.plot(df.valid_time,df.wspd, drawstyle='steps-mid', label='wspd')
ax2.set_ylabel('T2M (deg C), WSPD (m/s)')

# legend for both axes
h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2)

plt.show()


I deleted this because it consists almost entirely of a link. A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: add context around the link so others will have some idea what it is and why it's there, then quote the most relevant part in case the linked page is unavailable. If you [edit] this answer to add more once it is deleted, please flag it for moderator attention so that it can be un-deleted.
